# Removed all mozilla softwares

Tags: 12.04, mozilla

Hi wanted to remove Mozilla Firefox and i did

```
sudo apt-get purge mozilla-\*
```

It removed many other software too

What are the software I need to install again

Answer (score 0):

Look in the logs. In terminal, `cat /var/log/apt/history.log` should list the packages that you removed.